# Java : set generic parameters for a method

Tags: java-8, polymorphism

I have a method that can take ResponseEntity as parameter.

```
private ResponseEntity<OfferRest> mappedOfferByImagesEnabled(
        ResponseEntity<OfferRest> offerResponse) {

    for (OfferDetailImageRest image : 
                offerResponse.getBody().getOfferDetail().getImages()) {

        if (image.getDisabled()) {
            return offerResponse;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have the same method with another parameters: OfferEnity and I don't have need to call `getBody()` like the other one.

```
private OfferEntity mappedOfferByImagesEnabled(OfferEntity offerEntity) {
    for (OfferDetailImageEntity image : 
                 offerEntity.getOfferDetail().getImages()) {

        if (image.getDisabled()) {
            return offerEntity;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

My idea is to have a method with one (generic) parameter. Basing on the settings instance I will run the convenient code.

My question, How can I do it?

Comment: Why not make the method take a parameter of the type returned by `getOfferDetail()`? That way, you would just have to iterate over the incoming argument, and callers will call you with  `offerResponse.getBody().getOfferDetail()` or with `offerEntity.getOfferDetail()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method with  `OfferDetail` parameter

```
public boolean isImageDisabled(OfferDetail offerdetail) {
  return offerdetail.getImages().stream().anyMatch(Image::getDisabled));
 }
```

And the use it

```
isImageDisabled(offerEntity.getOfferDetail());
isImageDisabled(offerResponse.getBody().getOfferDetail());
```